# pass a variable name and evaluate it to that variable's value

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form with many buttons all of which print a value in the relevant textbox. the problem is the value is a fairly long text string and I would like to create a shorter variable eg. 'text' and make that variable equal to eg. 'some long sentence that I only want to type once'. any idea how I can edit this code to make this possible

```
  function setInput(button, setValue) {
var buttonVal = button.value,
    textbox = document.getElementById('input_' + buttonVal);
textbox.value = setValue;

<html> 
<input type='submit' name='submit_a' value="a" 
 onclick="setInput(this,'make_me_a_variable'); return false;">
 </html>
```

Comment: Here quick tip http://jsbeautifier.org/

Comment: Is this value used many times?

Comment: @user1557515 Do you use a JS library? `onclick` attributes and global functions are hardly a good approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a variable and assign your long text to the variable and use it where ever you want.

Modified code

```
 var longText = 'long text here'.
 function setInput(button) {
     var buttonVal = button.value,
     textbox = document.getElementById('input_' + buttonVal);
     textbox.value = longText ;
 }
```

Html:

```
<input type='submit' name='submit_a' value="a" 
 onclick="setInput(this); return false;">
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var textLookup = {
    btnName1: "Long text",
    btnName2: "Longer text"
};


// inside your function
var buttonText = ...,
    inputText = textLookup[buttonText];

// do stuff with inputText;
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of defining the event handler in the HTML code, you could also create the event handler with javascript. You need to do that in another event handler for document.onload. When you do it earlier, the input HTML element might not have been parsed and created yet, so no event handler for it can be added.

```
<script>
    // store your text in a variable
    var inputText = 'make_me_a_variable';
    // define some code which is executed when the page is loaded:
    document.addEventListener("load",function(event){
         // get the input by the id property I added to the HTML below.
          var input = document.getElementById('submit_a'); 
          // add an event handler for the click event (replaces the onclick HTML property)
          input.addEventListener("click",function(event) {
                setInput(this, inputText);
                return false;
          });
    });
</script>

[...]


 <input id="submit_a" type='submit' name='submit_a' value="a" >
```

Comment: That seems more logical I will keep it in mind as I develop the page. Thanks